# How to get all ID of my facebook application users?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I try to use facebook API. How to get all ID of my facebook application users?

This work for ID of my friends:

```
<?php
    require_once "auth/facebook/facebook.php";
  $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => '',
      'secret' => '',
    ));

  $app_id = '';
  $app_secret = '';

    $app_access_token = $app_id . '|' . $app_secret;

    $user = $facebook->getUser();


    if ($user) {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');


        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($friends["data"] as $value) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<div class="pic">';
            echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $value["id"] . '/picture"/>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="picName">'.$value["id"].'</div>'; 
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
?>
```

Is it possible? How to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get it from one single call.

You *can* log each id to a database every time a new user logs into your application.

```
 $user = $facebook->getUser();
 // Save $user to a database of your choice
```

Comment: This is only way? I don't want store this in database